# List Parent page with sub pages

Tags: pages

I have a page structure like this:

```
  Home

  Projects
   - Work_1
   - Work_2
   - Work_3
   - Work_4
```

Home and Projects are Pages. Work_1 - Work_4 are pages with Projects as their parent.

When I click the Projects page I'm using this code to get the children of Projects as a
sub menu, so I get Work_1 Work_2 Work_3 Work_4 as the sub menu.

```
  <?php
    if($post->post_parent)
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
    else
    $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
    if ($children) { ?>
    <ul>
    <?php echo $children; ?>
    </ul>
  <?php } ?>
```

How can I include include Projects in this sub menu so I get

Projects Work_1 Work_2 Work_3 Work_4

Hope I have explained this and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Found it thanks - thought I'd looked here but I must of missed it.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_Sub-Pages